# C# Type OCX DLL

Tags: c#, com-interop

How can I get the Name and Description from Methods and Events in a OCX or DLL?
The following example below I can get them from Properties. However, I could not find for Methods and Events.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

public class getinfocom
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Type oComType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2");
        dynamic oComInst = Activator.CreateInstance(oComType);

        Console.WriteLine("==========");
        Console.WriteLine("Properties");
        Console.WriteLine("==========");
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(oComInst))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.DisplayName + " | " + prop.Description);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("==========");
        Console.WriteLine("Methods");
        Console.WriteLine("==========");

        foreach (MethodInfo method in oComType.GetMethods())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(method.Name + " | " + method.Attributes + " | ");
        }


        Console.WriteLine("==========");
        Console.WriteLine("Events");
        Console.WriteLine("==========");

        EventDescriptorCollection events = TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(oComType);

        foreach (EventDescriptor myEvent in events)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myEvent.DisplayName + " | " + myEvent.Description);
        }


        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

I can see them through the Object Browser
[image]

Comment: Can you not add the DLL as a COM reference and just directly access the control using interop?

Comment: Works fine on my machine, although it triggered the Visio 2013 installer.  Ugh.  Really rather best to stay a mile away from this legacy COM component, it has nothing that isn't already wrapped by .NET and time has been very unkind to it, too many security fixes.  If you want a TreeView then just use the Winforms or WPF TreeView class.

Comment: I just remember never being able to skin this control and how it stuck out like a sore thumb on my screens (I was using Delphi at the time, LOL). Same deal with the COM grid control that Microsoft had around the same time.

Comment: This is only an example. Could be another component. I need the Name and Description for Methodes and Events. I have only Names for them.

Comment: Use a telephone and ask the author to modify his type library to include the [helpstring] attributes you want to use.  Significant odds you'll get an "Are you kidding?  Use the manual!" response but you won't know until you try.

Comment: I have checked some components that have the Description for properties, methods and events and I can see them in the IntelliSense tooltip or through the Object Browser. However, I couldn't find a way to get them using the Type Class programmatically. For properties it works ok. This legacy COM component in my example is this case. Hass Passant, I assume this is a Class limitation maybe I have to call Microsoft C# Team rsrsrsrsrs. I already tried everything buddy! I asked the community because always we can find people that know more than us. Thanks anyways.